# WPF CustomControl design advice

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I need to develope a WPF custom control to show the layout and connectivity of nodes in a wireless mesh network.  The user needs to be able to drag the nodes around.  The canvas should grown and Scrollbars should appear as required if elements get draged off the available space.  The ability to zoom in/out might be required.
My first take on this is to use a ListBox derived CustomControl with a Canvas based ItemsPanelTemplate.  To get things moving Im using Josh Smiths DragCanvas that allows UIElements children of the canvas to be dragged around.  My "node" class is not currently UIElement derived (the DragCanvas is currently working with the ListBoxItems that wrap my nodes).
**1. Is this a bacially sensible approach or should I be abonding the ListBox idea and going something lower level?**
2. I have to overlay the inter node link lines - not currently sure how to go about this (as a UIElement class that is part of the ControlTemplate?)
3. A few people seem to be having a headache with scrolbars in Canvases - is this going to be an issue?
**Any general or specific advice most appreciated.**
[image: Basic target look of final control]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, not bad as a control!

I am doing something similar, but it is not so simple.

1) IMHO, the DragCanvas is a basic way to host+drag elements. Since you will have to host labels (nodes), arcs and labels again (arcs' weight), I think the DragCanvas would be harder than write a custom control by yourself.

Not everything comes easy with templating: sometime is much better the "old" approach winforms-like, or even a hybrid way.

2) As stated, I'd create a Canvas-derived panel, which will host several UIElements (labels, arcs, etc). All of them should be governed by a model+viewmodel. That's a bit harder at the beginning, but it will give you a lot of satisfaction and flexibility in the future.

3) I don't think the Canvas will give you any headache! A Canvas full of elements has always a size of zero. That leads "headaches" for those trying to add a scrollviewer.

Instead, the Canvas-derived class (above) should override the MeasureOverride method, so that its size will fit any of the hosted objects. However, it is a bit annoying the fact you cannot use negative coordinates (it will cause scrolling problems).

It's hard to describe in few lines all the work behind a similar "editor". The task isn't easy, and the problems are many.

Hope it helps, anyway.

Cheers

Comment: Hi Mario - Thanks for your input. Yes I agree with your comments on DragCanvas.  From your comments in 2) can I read that to mean that you would abondone the ListBox base and you'd derive the customcontrol directly from Canvas?  On one hand I see ListControl or ItemsControl as being useful for selection etc but as you state on the other hand they dont necessarily fit a model where there is interaction between elements (arcs and arc weights).

Comment: The problem itself it that an ItemsControl maps an unique set of object (e.g. the nodes), but you should map the arcs, with their weight. Since they are *NOT* the same control, you should mix two or three ItemsControls together, and I find cumbersome instead of using a custom solution.
I really love WPF and its approach, but sometime is an overkill.

Comment: Ok Im going to look into deriving control directly from Canvas and managing the objects (nodes and arcs/links) my self - I'll see how that is going to look and maybe see if anyone else has any input.  Cheers.